# Github: branch & tag for rails engine which is associated directly with rails version?

Tags: git, github

There are several `rails engines` in our project. Each of the engines is corresponding to a specific `rails version`. For example, `engine A` has 2 copies - one copy for `rails 3.2` and another copy for `rails 4.0`. When committing `engine A` to `github`, we plan to create 2 `branches`: one `branch 3.2` for `rails 3.2` and another `branch 4.0` for `rails 4.0`. If there are `versions` needed for a branch, then we plan to use `git tag` within a branch to mark versions for a `branch`.

`Branch 3.2 and 4.0` will stay parallel and serve in rails 3.2 and 4.0 applications respectively. Does the git layout make sense? If it doesn't, what is the better way to handle `module` control on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes sense.

If you can diff your rails 3.2 and rails 4.0 code you can just import the 3.2 -> 4.0 changeset as one commit as a branch from 3.2 - you will then be able to work on one branch and just keep merging the branch into the other branch to keep them in sync. Obviously if the changes are too great between branches then the conflicts created at merge time just become unmanageable.

Remember the master branch is completely arbitrary convention and nothing inherently special you can make it be any branch.